# Using JQuery to display database information on a hover

Tags: jquery, database, hover

I'm trying to something with JQuery similar to [Red Box](http://www.redbox.com/Titles/AvailableTitles.aspx). I'd like to be able to hover over an entry in a table, and then have a box popup that displays information about that entry pulled from a database.

What I have so far is the ability to select specific elements in the table, and alert when I hover over those elements :)

So my question is: How do I display database information (using callbacks, I'm guessing) in a textbox that pops up from a jquery hover?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have server-side application that can return the proper JSON, the implementation would be like this:

```
$(".item").mouseenter(function(){
    var postUrl = $(this).href;
    // Get the JSON From server, and format the data into the box
    $.getJSON(postUrl, function (data) {
        showInfoBox(data);
    });
});

showInfoBox = function(data) {
    var ibox = $("#divInfoBox");
    $(".name", ibox).html(data.name);
    $(".description", ibox).html(data.description);
    // More data injection here

    ibox.show();

};
```

The relevant HTML will be something like:

```
<div id="divInfoBox">
    <h3 class="name"></h3>
    <p class="description"></p>
</div>

<.......>

<!-- list of the item that need database data !-->
<ul id="itemList">
    <li><a href="/url/to/data?id=1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/url/to/data?id=2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/url/to/data?id=3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the difference between mouseenter and hover?

Comment: hard to use word to explain, please
look at the example here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover#fn

Answer (score 1):

You could create a hidden `<div>` for each item during page generation as well (if the data isn't huge), and pull that data into your popup box.  This div could be hidden with jQuery - making people without javascript (namely google's crawler, and text readers) still get the "full description" data.

Then it just becomes a matter of positioning/showing your `<div>` when you hover. [hovertip](http://www.dave-cohen.com/node/1186) seems to be a good start.

Not having to request data through an AJAX call will make the page feel more 'responsive'

Comment: I like this answer, it's efficient and fast if the database (view) is less than about half a megabyte.  In the case that it is really a large database however, this method is infeasible.  Then we resort to AJAX pulling the divs down on request, like the OP asked for and the other answers have given.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this condensed description helps and should go along with the code xandy posted:

> I would create a dynamic page that
>   serves JSON.  The page would take the
>   key info to be able to pull that data
>   back.  I would then create a hover
>   event which would pass info to the
>   JSON about the product being hovered. 
>   When the data came back I would
>   populate that info into a DIV or use a
>   modal or tooltip plugin to display the
>   info.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple way to achieve this is via client-side templating, see [this blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/300754.aspx) for a detailed look at this.  As a summary, what client-side templating basically means is:

1. You have some HTML fragment in your page that represents the hover display element
2. Then using jquery you make an AJAX call to the server to get the data you want to display.
3. On receipt of the data from the AJAX call you use jquery to clone the html fragment.
4. Finally, you inject your received data into the cloned HTML fragment and display.

Hope that helps you out.